# nginx responses not accounting for conf settings

Tags: nginx

My conf for nginx has the following set in my http block:

```
gzip on;
server_tokens off;
add_header X-Frame-Options Deny;
expires 1s;
```

And none of them are actually accounted for in my response while using Chrome's dev console (F12).

My response header is:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Thu, 03 Oct 2013 15:36:25 GMT
ETag:"524d8e2a-55"
Last-Modified:Thu, 03 Oct 2013 15:32:58 GMT
Server:nginx/1.4.2
```

I'm on Windows, and have run the "nginx -s reload" command.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your issue move the X-Frame-Options line to the scope where you have other add_headers set.

Nginx will ignore the add_header in http if you have add_header say in the location scope.